# How to switch values in a column?

Tags: r

I have the following column:

```
ColA ColB
1     f
2     f
1     f
1     f
2     f
```

How do I switch the 1's to 2's and 2's to 1's in ColA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are only 1 and 2 values, we can make use of arithmetic to change the values

```
df1$ColA <- with(df1,  2- ColA + 1)
df1$ColA
#[1] 2 1 2 2 1
```

---

Or using `match`

```
match(df1$ColA, c(2, 1))
```

---

Or using `factor`

```
factor(df1$ColA, levels = 1:2, labels = 2:1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColA = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), ColB = c("f", "f", 
"f", "f", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve this using `transform` from `base r` with an `ifelse`.

```r
# Data: (h/t @akrun)

df1 <- structure(list(ColA = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), ColB = c("f", "f", 
"f", "f", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

# Code:

transform(df1, ColA = ifelse(ColA == 1, 2, 1))

# Output:

#>   ColA ColB
#> 1    2    f
#> 2    1    f
#> 3    2    f
#> 4    2    f
#> 5    1    f
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>